# How to read in other config information into a dropwizard service

Tags: dropwizard

I am building a dropwizard service which will connect to multiple data sources including mySQL and Elasticsearch.  All the mySQL settings can be defined in the yaml config file which gets read in after running from the commandline.

But what about other settings that I need to read in for other data sources that I will connect with myself, for example Elasticsearch?  Where can I define those settings?

I thought I could add another commandline Command - which I tried, but I can only run a single command (from the commandline) at a time - so I can't seem to run both the 'server' command as well as my custom command, 'custom' which is followed by the my own config file for elasticsearch.

How can I introduce settings either individually or from a file - which are defined at run time (not hard coded)?

Thanks

Anton

Comment: Dropwizard community [supports some modules](http://modules.dropwizard.io/). There is officially supported module for ElasticSearch - https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard-elasticsearch. You could study the source code for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the Dropwizard Core documentation on adding [custom configuration](http://www.dropwizard.io/1.2.2/docs/manual/core.html#configuration).

You'd create an `ElasticSearchFactory` class similar to the `MessageQueueFactory` in the example, reference this in your `Configuration` (that's in turn referenced in your `Application`), and then the options you need can be added to your main yaml configuration.